# Java Regex match zero times or once

Tags: java, regex, string

I was playing around with Regex in Java, and I wanted to match a string which has zero or one occurrence of a dot `.`. So I want any strings with a single dot or no dot to return true, and a string with two or more dots to return false.

According to the Java documentation:

> X?       X, once or not at all

So I have the following:

```
String str = "abc.def";
System.out.println(str.matches(".?"));
```

I was expecting `str` to match for `.` zero or one time, but it prints `false`.

Did I misinterpret the meaning of `?`? What can I do to make it match zero or one time only?

Comment: @Reimeus should it be `\\.?` instead?

Comment: `.` has a special meaning: It means any character.

Comment: `matches` will attempt to match full input not part of it.

Comment: @anubhava Is `^[^\\.]*\\.?[^\\.]*$` the minimal I need to provide to fulfil my requirement? I think you are good with regex, so I asked you..

Comment: Use `"^[^.]*\\.?[^.]*$"` since DOT doesn't need escaping inside `[..]`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your reply! You could have wrote your solution as well, I will gladly up vote it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct pattern is:

```
^[^.]*\\.?[^.]*$
```

First any number of characters which are not a dot, then optionally one dot followed by any number of characters which are not a dot.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works. Just a question. Is this the minimal amount of regex I need to provide for my requirement?

Comment: I don't think that it can be made shorter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will accept your solution in a while :)

Comment: Just realized it could be shorten by doing `"^[^.]*\\.?[^.]*$`

Comment: You might be able to work something out with reluctant qualifiers but it's harder to understand and more error prone.  This type of solution is the best based on experience.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the ^ and $ to denote the beginning and end.  If you are matching against strings that have newlines, this might make it work or not work depending on your needs and what options you set for the matcher. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

Comment: @JimmyT. What do you mean?

Comment: I've removed the \\ in the [ ]

Comment: Note that this is the minimal pattern if you are using `String.matches()` which requires the pattern to match the entire string in order to return `true`.  (Kind of a silly interpretation of `matches()` in my opinion, but that is how Java does it.)  If you are using `matcher.find()` then it will return true just with `\\.?` because that method simply looks for the pattern to be present anywhere in the string.  But matcher takes a lot more effort to set up.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want: `([^\.]*\.[^\.]*)?` It will match any string that contains any number of non-dots, followed by a single dot followed by any number of non-dots that occurs zero or once.  You'll need to escape your escapes for Java string literals which looks like this: `([^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*)?`

Comment: How is different from Jimmy T's solution?

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar - they're both Jimmy!

Comment: I didn't see that solution when I posted this answer.  The differences should be clear but both work.  Mine has fewer characters but I don't think that is important.

Comment: @JimmyJames Your solution is fine too, and +1 for my gratitude (and the solution).

Comment: thanks.  I put a comment above about multiline mode.  If you want to match on newlines, you'll need to consider that option.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation from the given solutions as proposed by user `anubhava`, we can use:

```
^[^.]*\\.?[^.]*$
```

According to him, `.` does not need to be escaped within the square brackets `[ ]`

---

***All credits to user `anubhava`***